# Get keys from Flow object type in code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, flowtype

Is it possible to get the keys from a Flow object type definition in the app code (in other words, are Flow type definition reified in runtime code in any way)?

Use case:

```
type Props = {
  userID: string,
  size: number | PhotoSize,
  subscribePresence: Function,
  unsubscribePresence: Function,
  presenceStatus: ?PresenceStatus,
  photoURL: ?string,
  userName: ?string,
};

class Photo extends Component<Props> {
  // ...
  render() {
    const { userID, size, presenceStatus } = this.props;
    // Other props used elsewhere in the component
    const restProps = _.omit(this.props, ???)
  }
}
```

The spread destructure (`const { /* etc */ ... rest} = this.props`) wouldn't work because there are other props that don't get used in `render`. However, I'd like to pick up other props that might've been specified (`className`, `id`, etc).

Can `???` be derived from something analogous to `Object.keys(Props)`? As far as I can tell, the type definitions are compiled away, so attempting to reference `Props` in runtime code throws a `RuntimeError: Props is not defined`.

Comment: No, all type information is stripped out at compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow provides static type analysis and all Flow code is stripped before runtime (flow annotations are not valid Javascript code).

To achieve what you want, you need to have the information about your expected Props available after you strip Flow code. You could do that by setting [defaultProps](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props) for all props in your component and then you could write:

```
const restProps = _.omit(this.props, Photo.defaultProps)
```

Setting defaultProps is usually a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks Tomas; seems like `defaultProps` are the closest I'll get